# simple JavaScript code to show and hide data

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have problem with my code. On click "show button", I want to hide the button and show "data". But the data is not appearing. What is the problem?

```js
 function my() {
        var yy = document.getElementById("show");
        yy.style.display="none";
     
       var b = document.getElementById("data");
        b.style.display="block";
      
      
      
    }
```

```css
    #hide{ display:none;}
     


    #show{ display:true;} 
     
     

    #data{ display: none;}
```

```html
     


    <div id="data"> this i s some data </div>
    <input onclick="my()" type="button" id="show" value="show data">
    <input type="button" id="hide" value="hide data">
```

Comment: `b.style.display="true";` makes no sense. There’s not `display: true;`.

Comment: I use  this code >> $('#data').show(); it does not affect

Comment: `display:true` is not valid property,use `block` instead of `true`.

Comment: Did you want to `toggle` show / hide ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an element's class with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To toggle the div this is the code using `Javascript`.

```js
document.getElementById("hide").onclick=function(){
  document.getElementById("data").style.display="none";
  }
document.getElementById("show").onclick=function(){
  document.getElementById("data").style.display="block";
  }
```

```html
<div id="data"> this is some data </div>
<input type="button" id="show" value="show data">
<input type="button" id="hide" value="hide data">
```